# How to test UseHttpsRedirection setting locally in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

In my ASP.NET Core project, I have turned ON HTTPS Redirection, with this setting in my Program.cs:
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

I have referred to [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Locally, when I run my Core Web project, it uses https by default (https://localhost:7432/).  Now, to test if redirection from http -> https works, I browse to http://localhost:7432/, but I get a "This page isn’t working right now" error.

So, how do I test if this redirection is working locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Properties/launchSettings.json* file, you'll see a property for `applicationUrl` that looks like this:

```json
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7250;http://localhost:5097"
```

This sets up the app to listen on two different ports: *7250* for HTTPS and *5097* for HTTP. In your specific project, find the HTTP URL and use that to test the HTTPS redirection locally.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, you can't share the same port for both `http` and `https`. Instead, you should define the ports in the `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.Production.json`. FYI, I never define such thing in `appsettings.json`, because that file is typically part of the repository. To me, the best place is in the other file.

In one of those files, you should see (or add whereas not present) something like this:

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://*:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://*:5001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "(your certificate file)",
          "Password": "(your certificate password)"
        },
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AllowInvalid": true,
  "https_port": 443,
  ...
```

Doing so, when you try to call your site as `http`, it will attempt to switch to the other port, using `https`.

For sure not the best explaination, but that's what I know about the `https` redirection.